Tuned IF amplifier saturation
I was designing a tuned IF amplifier. I went with a staged Amplifier design with freqeuncy of 10Mhz. While reading through different sources, i found out that we get about max 5mV amplitude from an antenna, and we would need about 50-300mV RMS, for our FM demodulator stage.
I designed a amplifier which gives about 7-10dB gain, about (15mV amplitude only). If i make my gain go higher, my output is getting saturated, im thinking, im not able to bias it properly.
Is there any source like a textbook/video which explains about staged tuned alpifiers, which work.


Designing L-C tuned I.F. amplifiers is a bit difficult. Have you considered using commercial 10.7 MHz ceramic filters instead? Much easier to design a compatible amplifier, since most ceramic filters have low-impedance (about 330 ohms)... low enough that stable amplifiers happily amplify without oscillations. A few cascaded stages might be good, followed by a stage designed specifically as a limiting amplifier before the FM detector.

This is the easy way out. However, I was doing this to learn RF concepts, so I wanted to take the hard way since it would help me understand concepts.

I assume this is a continuation of your previous question in designing a VHF FM broadcast receiver.
It would be helpful to know whether you plan to use a quadrature, ratio, or Foster-Seeley detector. Each design has pros and cons, and they differ in the input signal level/impedance.
In short, your amplifier's insufficient gain is in part due to the very small VCE (see the next paragraph) and local feedback from the Cob of the transistors. For higher gain and stability, I recommend adopting a different topology. The bias points (24.5mA and 31mA) are about right for that transistor; changing them cannot greatly improve the amplifier.
The clipping amplitude can be increased by designing the loadline so that the VCE is about half of the Vcc. Currently, the emitter resistor takes up about 3V, and the 250 in the collector takes up 6 to 7.5V, so those leave tiny room for the VCE swing. That is not good for dynamic range and the gain. I would reduce or eliminate those 250 ohms, perhaps reduce the two 100's in the emitter, and adjust the base current bleeder resistors to keep the collector current around 10-25mA range where both hFE and fT are near maxima simultaneously.
The IF amplifier for the FM receiver should have an IF filter (typically a ceramic filter or doubly-tuned LC filter, perhaps two of them) and an ample 50-80dB gain total. This is because you'll want an amplitude limiter (i.e., saturation) after the filter to maximize the noise immunity advantage of FM modulation. Typically, a 4-stage differential amplifier coupled with a tuned transformer is considered a classic design—study the spec sheet of TA7060AP (Toshiba) and CA3053 (Harris).
A good example to study is Revox B760 (I recently worked on it), whose IF amplifier block is:

where each CA3053 is a single-stage differential amplifier. Revox B760 does a lot of intricate tricks in other areas, partly because the components back then were not as good as today but tried to their best. But the IF amp is very straightforward. (The filter is perhaps somewhat overkill but that's Revox. The actual boards are also beautifully built, just like broadcast-grade equipment from that era.)
As a sidenote, AM/FM radios are difficult to use for this illustration because those radios typically used 455kHz/10.7MHz double-decker construction for AM and FM. But it looks like this:

which is Becker Mexico Cassette 375, which was factory standard with Mercedes, Ferrari and others. TR203-205, 207 are the IF amp. TR203 and 207 are for FM only, but 204-205 are shared with AM. TR206 is for signal detection to drive the mechanical station-seeking function (You should see how the mechanism is implemented! It reminds me of the very first lock-needle automatic exposure function in Konica 35mm SLRs in the 1960s. That mechanism requires good cleaning and lubrication to revive.) I've worked on a few of those, and those old RF/IF transistors are holding up surprisingly well.
Of the two types, I recommend the Revox design as the starting point for your project. It is much better design for FM IF amplifier. The Becker car stereo design (ignoring/bypassing the AM IFTs) would work but not note how diodes are used to implement the amplitude limiter.
Also, study TA7302P + TA7303P (Toshiba) or CA3089, CA3189 (Harris) for the IF chain and FM detector. Those Toshiba chips were typical FM radio ICs from the late 1970s to the early 1980s. I think the Harris ones were for more performance-oriented applications. (Don't buy those chips, but study them.) Philips must have similar products for the same market, but I don't know, top of my head.
The advantage of using a differential amplifier in the unbalanced mode in the above example ICs is to minimize the effect of feedback capacitors (Cob) in the amplifier stages, which kills the high-frequency gains. In your circuits, the Ic are set at 24.5mA in the first stage and 31mA in the second stage, where fT is around 300MHz. Theoretically, if you can eliminate the feedback from the Cob's, you would be getting well in excess of 40dB gain, but you are only getting 7dB due to the local feedbacks. A differential amplifier with an unbalanced load works just like a cascode amplifier with a built-in amplitude limiter, which is ideal for FM IF amplifiers.
The tube-generation people would mention a technique called feedback neutralization or simply neutralization. That technique can certainly be used, but it complicates the design and tuning/alignment process. It is not worthwhile doing at 10MHz with today's transistors because better RF transistors and better circuit topology lead to better overall engineering tradeoffs. (Neutralization was commonly used in FM transistor radios until the early or mid-1970s. In the Becker Mexico above, C209, C223, C232, C247, C254 are neutralization capacitors. BF451 they used have better RF properties than BC547C but still needed neutralization.)
You could also use a transistor of higher RF gain (such as 2SC3355; the original was NEC but the Chinese copies are available. Some have wrong pin assignments so be careful).
Another factor is impedance matching (loadline design). The collector output impedance should be taken at a higher impedance than assumed in that circuit design. I would use a transformer or a T-network at the end. (although I would really use a different topology to begin with)
Regarding textbooks, few people prefer to design an FM IF amplifier using discrete transistors because ICs are available and are easier/cheaper overall. Those mentioned above are classic ICs whose data sheets give a little insight into how the internal circuits work. Modern ICs are much more integrated and black-box. Also, FM IF amplifiers have somewhat distinct design requirements compared to IF amps for AM/SSB/CW/other modes, video amplifiers, line drivers, etc. since those all have to be linear. Finally, RF amplifiers typically built with discrete transistors have very different requirements than FM IF amps. So, a lot of available materials would not apply to your problem at hand. I think high-bandwidth analog electronics textbooks are of interest to you, especially those for integrated circuit designers. These were typically used in 3rd or 4th year of electrical engineering majors in decent universities, but I think most schools got rid of those subjects, so you may have to look for classic textbooks (as is often the case with analog/RF anything). The electrical engineering college curriculum today is more like a generic quantitative engineering.
I don't know if anyone is really interested in what I mean by the classics, but these are my coffeetable reading:

and this is on my lunch table:

Gray and Meyer is a true classic. Anyone who does analog must have studied it at some point. It does not discuss RF/IF amps, but it does discuss the high-frequency analysis of single-stage diff amps and multi-stage amps. I'm not sure how well-known Soclof is, but it is a good catalog of standard techniques as of the 1980s. It discusses video amplifiers, for example. Both of these books are recommended only to those who have solid theoretical foundations and are determined to go super deep dive.
Bowick is more like a collection of really good cheat sheets on today's RF engineering. It's handy but does not necessarily give you the foundation. It certainly does not get into discrete component IF amplifier design. The photo is of the 2nd edition (2008), but the original is kinda classic among practicing engineers. What was added in the 2008 edition is already old. But what was in the 1st edition is still current.

nice answer! On the claim on colleges: of course, colleges do teach electronics basics in their EE courses, but when it goes into the advanced/niche topic courses, they will of course rather teach their students modern, relevant technologies. How to build an HF amplifier from discrete components is not very relevant – because neither is that frequency range interesting, nor would one do that, as you say, from discrete components these days. The engineers that still do that would be the ones designing modern ICs, and they wouldn't be purely analog designs. So, I'd give colleges a bit more …

… credit here. They do excellent, specialized education – but not unless you really try to find that, not into things that are primarily of historical interest. Sure, RF analog amplifier design is still a common topic – my alma mater has an institute that mostly does RF analog hardware – but that these days has nothing to do with BC547 on a PCB, but with microwave design, chip design, packaging, 70-GHz probing… these kinds of things are what they educate students in. So, if you specialize in analog design for RF, you'd be learning something that's more modern than what OP tries to do! And I

… think that's OK. Nobody would want computer scientists at university to learn how to design computers and computer software with the technical possibilities and focus that the 1960s had, to make an analogy. College focus moves on – in the end, things that are basics are still taught, and everything that is specialized can be learned from a book, with students being enabled to learn even niche things that they haven't been taught at uni through the wider focus they get when being confronted with the teaching of the modern content their professors deem relevant for the students and for science

All that is true, but to make a high-performance microwave system, you'd still need to design precision circuitry to handle the baseband or IF... although in many cases, the IF is sampled, and the rest is done in DSP. Now, DSP and stochastic processes are thinned out except for the bare basics in the 3rd and 4th year curriculum. Analog Devices and other companies are permanently looking for analog/RF engineers. Their recruiters are busy. New weapons systems rely on custom solutions but the scale of their demand is beyond our imagination.

Anyway, I just described the reality and did not complain about the curriculum. Private institutions need to maintain their prestige and endowments; public universities need to produce useful labor. We amateurs need to stay above that level to truly enjoy what we do. That's all.

By the way, none of these courses were offered when I was in college. Circuit theory, real and complex analysis, electromagnetics, thermodynamics, linear systems (continuous and discrete), analog and digital electronics, probability/statistics, stochastic, DSP, comm theory, speech/auditory signal processing, and microwave theory.  I did a lot of extracurricular stuff, though. I got a lot of classic books from retiring professors because I asked them to dis-retire to teach their classes. They didn't want to teach any more but had me clean up their offices.

Ha! "Now, DSP and stochastic processes are thinned out except for the bare basics in the 3rd and 4th year curriculum" up to three years ago, I used to teach halls on "probability theory for EEs", 3rd semester, bringing forth stochastic processes for the 5th semester "digital comms I" course, where in parallel people do "signals and system" (curriculum different, but roughly same scope as Opennheim&Schafer's course/textbook). Sure, we fading channels and stuff is then for "Comms engineering II", and that's only for these students that specialize in comms, but that was definitely all pretty …

… solid. There of course still was circuit theory (linear: 1.semester, low-freq semiconductor circutry: 2. semester), real and complex analysis (Higher Math 1 through 4), digital electronics. "Fields and Wave phenomena" was the first RF lecture (mandatory, 3. semester, mostly: Maxwell), then "Basics of High Frequency" (mandatory, 4th, Maxwell applied to come to transmission line theory, mostly), "Microwave Engineering" (mandatory for many specializations, not all) and many others from that field (Radar engineering, radio systems design, antenna systems, microwave measurements, spaceborne…)

Excellent to get their books! I think what I take away from this is that a) colleges have very different evolution of focus, b) material is out there, as has always been, and b) demand is as high as it always has been.

When I was there, we could choose DSP chain of courses with Oppenheim-Scafer-Buck (previous edition) or Proakis. My advisor was Buck, so I took the Proakis chain. So, I essentially studied both books at some point. Oppenheim required to solve all exercise problems to learn all the neat tricks, but Proakis describes everything in the text so the latter is more convenient as a reference in my research work.

Oh I forgot I also took semiconductor material/device chain of courses. That professor since then stopped teaching it and now teaching machine learning and AI. How does taht happen?

Well, KIT does still teach that (when I studied it, it was split into multiple courses; "Solid State Electronics", and "Semiconductor Devices", and it was one of the harder things we did, among maybe our Control Systems courses.); I hope they focused it a bit more. Learned way more in a mandatory foundations course on even esoteric devices (PINN- devices anyone?), but the basics were solid. Here's how that happens: New methods become important, so professors decide to teach them. This might simply have been a "how many students will benefit if I do B instead of A?" trade-off. Sad,but sensible.

The inventor of the PIN family of devices, Nishizawa, was a professor in the area I grew up, and he did a lot of public lectures. I used to go to those when I was a little kid. He also did a lot of TV lectures and a few documentaries were made about his work (some containing really embarrassing scenes but apparently he didn't care.). He was very proud of the inventions but also super bitter how the Japanese industry failed to take advantage of them and had to buy the rights from the US companies that he sold to. He passed away several years ago.

On one hand, super cool, on the other hand, quite a bit sad.
